# Store Kafka streamed data to specific volume on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have two volumes attached to my AWS EC2 CentOS 7, `primary` and `secondary`. If I execute certain operations that require downloading and storing of data, how do I specify the storage path?

For eg., I would like to stream a Kafka data into a text file to be stored in the secondary volume. If I run the following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic my_kafka_topic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server "my_dns:9092" | tee output.txt
```

the data stream is written into file `output.txt` stored on the `primary` volume automatically. How do I specify for it to store on the `secondary` volume.

I can find the filesystem paths with `df -h`, and this is what I see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G   17M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   58G   20G   38G  35% /
/dev/nvme1n1     60G   33M   60G   1% /opt/data/datadir1
```

where `/dev/nvme1n1` is the `secondary` volume.
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `output.txt`, specify a file path on the other volume eg `/opt/data/datadir1/output.txt`

Comment: @jordanm Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> stored on the primary volume automatically

No, it isn't. That just happens to be where you run the command. You can `cd` to the other volume directory first, then the command will work as you want.

However, you should specify an absolute path for the file on the mounted volume rather than the relative-path of the current directory where you run the command.

Comment: I have multiple volumes on my ec2 instance, how should I use other volume for my log.dirs in kafka broker? I ran out of space and my kafka died.

Comment: @JayPatel That property accepts a comma separated list of directories